# Did C-124 loadmasters receive parachute and water survival training?

Tags: military, flight-training, us-air-force, parachute

When the position of "loadmaster" was created for the [Douglas C-124 Globemaster II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-124_Globemaster_II), did prospective USAF loadmasters attend the parachute training and water survival school at the 3904th Training Squadron at Fort Carson, Colorado? I believe this school later moved to Stead AFB, Nevada, later the Naval Air Station at Pensacola, Florida (until 2015), and now Fairchild AFB, Washington.

Comment: While not a direct answer to the specifically pointed question - the Evolution of the Loadmaster career field: https://www.airforcemag.com/article/1211evolution/

Comment: Probably not.  Because if they do now they didn't in 1984, and the globemaster is a lot older than that.